# How to deal with a bad bounty topic

Tags: discussion, bounty

I should caveat this by saying I'm not asking how to close a question with a bounty. This has to do with a question that was borderline but still within bounds (the question was specific to a given API) that was subsequently given a bounty (by a different user) that asks for information that

- Were it a separate question would be off topic
- Asks for information that the base thread already addressed

[ACH Payment transfer with Paypal in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142604/ach-payment-transfer-with-paypal-in-php)

> 0 down vote favorite I am trying to search a api of paypal to transfer money from paypal account to bank account means ACH payment

It's a waste of a bounty on his part because there's no such API (I'm not sure if he read my answer or not). Do I just let it play out or should I flag it to remove the bounty?

Comment: In general, closing a bountied question requires a custom moderator flag.  Just be specific with your explanation.  And of course, it does have to be off-topic.  If the question is not closable, just leave it alone.

Comment: SO users are never happy with a "you can't do that" answer.  There isn't any way to stop them from wanting to do it anyway, they'll certainly consider a bounty to keep fishing.  The Q+A is now protected because of the bounty so nothing anybody can do.  It will only last for a week :)  Maybe you'll get some extra votes, the glass is half-full.

Comment: *0 down vote favorite* c'mon man.  Srs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you should *not* be trying to cancel some other person's bounty, they should be free to spend their rep as they see fit, even on things you consider foolhardy. Note that the question itself is okay (according to you, though I make no judgment on that myself) so it shouldn't be touched.

The *first* comment bounty giver seems to use is:

> Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.

and the remainder is just echoing the original paragraph from the question itself, including the up and down vote buttons rendered as text, so almost certainly a cut and paste job.

So, really, this seems to be just a request to get more answers to *exactly the same* question, but with some official citation. Given your statement that the original question, though borderline, was acceptable to you, I can't really see how this type of bounty could be *un*acceptable.

Hence, were I you (and I'm clearly not), I would perhaps be thinking about beefing up your answer *with* such a credible source, even if that just makes it *clearer* that what they're asking for is not possible/allowed/supported/even-remotely-sane.

Then you may well *get* the bounty.